# Datatables column search not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am applying column search to but text box appears first time against each column but search is not enabled when I sort any column text box also disappears. Simply column search is not working correctly

```
var table = "";
var fillDataTable = function(sitesList) {
  table = $("#locationListTable").DataTable({
    "aaData": sitesList,
    'dom': 'lfrti',
    'scrollX': true,
    'scrollY': 300,
    'scroller': true,
    'deferRender': true,
    'paging': false,
    'bSort': true,
    'colReorder': true,
    'bSortCellsTop': false,
    'bAutoWidth': true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    'destroy': true,
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData) {

      //     $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href="' + path.AppPath + 'Membership/Member/Detail/' + aData.memberId + '">' + aData.lastName + '</a>');
      //     $('td:eq(0)', nRow).addClass('member-' + aData.status);
      //     $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="' + path.AppPath + 'Membership/Member/Detail/' + aData.memberId + '">' + aData.firstName + '</a>');
      //     if (aData.status === "Active") {
      //         $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html('<span class="text-success">' + aData.status + '</span>');
      //     }
      //     if (aData.status === "Inactive") {
      //         $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html('<span class="text-danger">' + aData.status + '</span>');
      //     }
    },
    "aoColumns": [{
      data: 'company.name',
      defaultContent: 'N/A',
      'sWidth': '10%'
    }, {
      data: 'city',
      defaultContent: 'N/A',
      'sWidth': '12%'
    }, {
      data: 'name',
      defaultContent: 'N/A',
      'sWidth': '5%'
    }, {
      data: 'phoneNumber',
      defaultContent: 'N/A',
      'sWidth': '10%'
    }, {
      data: 'state',
      defaultContent: 'N/A',
      'sWidth': '10%'
    }, {
      data: 'zip',
      defaultContent: 'N/A',
      'sWidth': '10%'
    }]
  });
  new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder(table, {
    iFixedColumnsRight: 1
  });
  //jquery datatable events 
};
fillDataTable($scope.sitesList);
table.on('column-reorder', function(e, settings, details) {});
$('#locationListTable tfoot th').each(function() {
  debugger
  var title = $('#locationListTable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search"' + title + ' />')
});
table.columns().every(function() {
  debugger
  console.log(this.data);
  var dataTableColumn = this;
  $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function() {
    debugger
    dataTableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});
```

Comment: Create a fiddle with your code, including the html.